# Unable to open flutter app from CMD but opens from Android Studio. Pubspec.yaml error

Tags: flutter

D:>flutter run
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Comment: ...okay? _Did_ you run this from the root of your Flutter project? What part of the error message is unclear? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are not running the command from the correct flutter project path.

A possible solution could be,

- Navigate to your respective flutter project folder
  **cd project-name**

Now run `flutter run`. Hopefully, this should work

A way to debug is to run `ls` in your terminal. That would list the projects available in the directory. If not switch to the respective path using the above command